# View is not found after adding a context

Tags: python, acl, pyramid

I'm trying to add an ACL to a view in a Pyramid project

I've got a working minimal test:

```
config.add_route('foo', '/foo')
```

view:

```
@view_config(route_name='foo', renderer='../templates/foo.jinja2',
             permission='view', context=Foo)
def foo(request):
    return {}
```

context:

```
class Foo:
    __acl__ = [
        (Allow, Everyone, 'view'),
    ]
```

Which works great without the permission and context set, but after adding them, I get `pyramid.httpexceptions.HTTPNotFound: /foo`.

Why is this route suddenly not found? This is almost exactly copied from the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not specify the context in the `view_config`, but specify a factory in your route.

```
config.add_route('foo', '/foo', factory=lambda r: Foo(r))
```

Also, you may have to accept the request in your `__init__`:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, request):
        pass

    __acl__ = [
        (Allow, Everyone, 'view'),
    ]
```

The way you did it (using `context` in the `view_config`) means "if the context is `Foo`, use that view function". It's a predicate.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference between this and the `context=` in the tutorial: https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki/authorization.html#add-permission-declarations - if the context matches `.models.Page` in that case - where does that object come from?

Comment: Right, I just noticed that there's a `config.set_root_factory(root_factory)` in that example, which explains a lot!